# Development plugin to view and manage scheduled wordpress cron jobs?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

Is there a plugin for wordpress that can help a user to view and manage the crons that are currently schdeuled in WordPress? I have looked into Core control but doesn't allow the user to manage the cron jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP-Crontrol.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-crontrol/